# MongoDB insert data to an existing user in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I wanna ask if you can insert some NEW data to an existing User,

Without adding them from before but only by defining them in the model.

Is that possible and if yes how?

Please let me know if you didn't understand any part of this.

Comment: mongo supports upsert functionality.  Can you please post some code as to what you have tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything cause i didn't know if that was possible.

Comment: @akaphenom I just searched that. Do you mean with the update function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

```
mongodb.someCollection.update(
  {/* some query to match the record or not */},
  {/* record to update OR record to insert if no match */},
  {
     /* options */
     upsert: true
  }
)
```

Comment: I think that's what i want it to do yeah. Thanks a lot i think this going to work for me HUGE Thanks again.